# Undo on the paint in drawing view android studio? Color of other paths changing on the second time

Tags: android

Here is my android Draw view class where i implemented draw and undo

```
class DrawingView extends View {
Paint mPaint;
Bitmap mBitmap;
Canvas mCanvas;
Path mPath;
float x, y;
private ArrayList<Path> paths = new ArrayList<Path>();
private ArrayList<Path> undonePaths = new ArrayList<Path>();
private ArrayList<Paint> mpaints = new ArrayList<Paint>();

Paint mBitmapPaint;

public DrawingView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    mPaint = new Paint();
    mPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
    mPaint.setDither(true);
    mPaint.setColor(0xFFFF0000);
    mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    mPaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
    mPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
    mPaint.setStrokeWidth(20);
    mPath = new Path();
    mBitmapPaint = new Paint();
}

@Override
protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
    super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);

    if (w == 0) {
        w = 1080;
    }
    if (mBitmap == null) {
        mBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

    } else {
        h = mBitmap.getHeight();
        w = mBitmap.getWidth();
        mBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    }
    if (mCanvas == null)

    {
        mCanvas = new Canvas(mBitmap);
    } else {
        mCanvas = null;
        mCanvas = new Canvas(mBitmap);
    }

}

@Override
public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.draw(canvas);


    for (int i = 0; i < paths.size(); i++) {
        canvas.drawPath(paths.get(i), mpaints.get(i));
        canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap, 0, 0, mpaints.get(i));
    }
   /* for (int i = 0; i < paths.size(); i++) {
        canvas.drawPath(paths.get(i), mPaint);
        canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap, 0, 0, mBitmapPaint);
    }*/

}

public void onClickUndo() {
    if (paths.size() > 0) {

        undonePaths.add(paths.remove(paths.size() - 1));

        for (int i = 0; i < undonePaths.size(); i++) {
            mCanvas.drawColor(0, PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR);

            mPaint = new Paint(mPaint);

         /*   Path path   = this.undonePaths.get(i);
            Paint paint=this.mpaints.get(i);
            mCanvas.drawPath(path, paint);*/
            /*mCanvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap, 0, 0, mBitmapPaint);*/

        }
        invalidate();


    }

}

private float mX, mY;
private static final float TOUCH_TOLERANCE = 4;

private void touch_start(float x, float y) {
    mPath.reset();
    undonePaths.clear();
    mPath.reset();
    mPath.moveTo(x, y);
    mX = x;
    mY = y;
}

private void touch_move(float x, float y) {
    float dx = Math.abs(x - mX);
    float dy = Math.abs(y - mY);
    if (dx >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE || dy >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE) {
        mPath.quadTo(mX, mY, (x + mX) / 2, (y + mY) / 2);
        mX = x;
        mY = y;
    }
}


private void touch_up() {
    mPath.lineTo(mX, mY);
    // commit the path to our offscreen
    mCanvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);
    paths.add(mPath);

    mPath = new Path();
    mpaints.add(mPaint);
    mPaint = new Paint(mPaint);

}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    x = event.getX();
    y = event.getY();

    switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            touch_start(x, y);

            invalidate();
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            touch_move(x, y);
            invalidate();
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            touch_up();
            invalidate();
            break;
    }
    return true;
}
```

The problem is undo is working fine for very first time. But once I clear all drawings and try to draw again and undo it the colour of remaining paths changing. But it is working fine on the very first time.

Answer (score 0):

Hello guys by debugging I finally solved this issue. Update this method

```
 public void onClickUndo() {


    if (paths.size() > 0) {

        undonePaths.add(paths.remove(paths.size() - 1));
        mpaints.remove(paths.size());
        invalidate();

    }
}
```